# updating width of custom view is not going in the right direction

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios-animations

I've created a custom view. added width, height, and centerY constraints.

[image]

I used it in a storyboard.

[image]

I want to add a label, increase the width animately. and after 1.5 seconds I need to remove the label and decrease the width animatedly.

I wrote the below code inside my custom view.

```
fileprivate func unfoldMeAnimatedly() {
        self.labelLeadingToStatusImageView.isActive = true
        self.updateStatusLabel()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.constraints.forEach { (constraint) in
            if constraint.identifier == "widthOfCardDraftStatus" {
                constraint.constant = 95
            }
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (finished) in
        }
    }

    fileprivate func foldMeAnimatedly() {
        self.constraints.forEach { (constraint) in
            if constraint.identifier == "widthOfCardDraftStatus" {
                constraint.constant = 24
            }
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
            //self.statusLabel.alpha = 0.0
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (finished) in
        }
    }
```

invoking animations

```
unfoldMeAnimatedly()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1.5) {
    self.foldMeAnimatedly()
}
```

privew of result:

[image]

I did not understand why it is moving. the desired one is just the width needs to be increased/decrease at only one end. i.e right side.

Few observations:
It's strange that I changed the animation durations to 0.5, 0.5 and wait time to 0.5. now it is working as expected.

[image]

Why like this? Anybody can explain why it's behaving like this or some issue with code?

Comment: I think the problem is about `ViewController`'s `StatusView`'s width constraint, could you please add the `StatusView` constraints in `ViewController`?

Comment: Width is added to ViewController. I'm updating it inside view.

Comment: If you look at how the view is moving to the left, it is not happening inside of an animation block. It is quite sudden. What happens if you comment out the the lines that deactivate the other constraints: labelTrailingToSuperView and labelLeadingToStatusImageView? It may also help if you explain what those constraints are.

Comment: Updated the code. Those are constraints of a label. I've removed them and not updating them. it there any limitation for animations till 1.5 seconds only. @Rob

Comment: If I were you I'd get rid of your DispatchQueue. You should chain your unfold and fold animations together by calling fold from your UIView.animate completion block. Use the delay parameter to set the 1.5 second delay (or whatever). Also, make sure to call layoutIfNeeded on the SUPERVIEW! Not on your custom view.

Comment: Awesome. superview.layoutIfNeeded() did the trick here. perfect @Rob . Thank you so much. Now I also used chaining.